# Why the result is 8?

Tags: javascript, math, operations

Today I had a job interview on JS and one of the questions was

*What is the value of a*

`var a = (3,5 - 1) * 2;`

Hmm I assumed its 8 (the chrome dev console also gives it 8) but I don't know why it is eight. Why the `3` is omitted? I mean of course you can't do any operations with it but still, it disappears, or I am wrong?

Please go easy on me. I am trying to understand. Any articles on this kind of operations would be highly appreciated

Comment: See this blog post. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: That's not a `.` for floating point. That's a comma operator (the kind you see in for loops) which groups statements in one statment and evaluating to the result of the last.

Comment: I see, Thank you @Augwa for the article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`Comma Operator | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator),

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last (right-most) operand.

So, `var a = (3,5 - 1) * 2;` returns `4 * 2 = 8`

Comment: `(3,5-1)` evaluates to `4`

Comment: _...the value of the last (left-most) operand_, he said!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, it was a mistake. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Yeah I replaced the downvote with an upvote. The other downvote is probably going to stay there as the downvoter is probably left ages ago.

Answer (score 2):

`3,5` it's not `3.5` (float). See [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

3,5 equals 5.

`(3,5 - 1) * 2` translates to `(5 - 1) * 2` which is 8.

Comment: I know its not a float but now I will know about comma operator :D

Comment: Check the link I provided!

Answer (score 1):

See this reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

The comma operator evaluates all of the expressions listed and returns the last one. So your expression simplifies to

(5 - 1) * 2